# Remove weights from networkx graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have a weighted Networkx graph G. I first want to make some operation on G with weights (which is why I just don't read the input and set weights=None) and then remove them from G afterwards. What is the most straightforward way to make it unweighted?

I could just do:

```
G = nx.from_scipy_sparse_array(nx.to_scipy_sparse_array(G,weight=None))
```

Or loop through the G.adj dictionary and set weights=0, but both of these options feels too complicated. Something like:

```
G = G.drop_weights()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the data structure of the networkx graphs directly and remove any unwanted attributes.
At the end, what you can do is define a function that loops over the dictionaries and remove the "weight" attribute.

```py
def drop_weights(G):
    '''Drop the weights from a networkx weighted graph.'''
    for node, edges in nx.to_dict_of_dicts(G).items():
        for edge, attrs in edges.items():
            attrs.pop('weight', None)
```

and an example of usage:

```py
import networkx as nx

def drop_weights(G):
    '''Drop the weights from a networkx weighted graph.'''
    for node, edges in nx.to_dict_of_dicts(G).items():
        for edge, attrs in edges.items():
            attrs.pop('weight', None)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from([(1,2,0.125), (1,3,0.75), (2,4,1.2), (3,4,0.375)])

print(nx.is_weighted(G)) # True

F = nx.Graph(G)
print(nx.is_weighted(F)) # True

# OP's suggestion
F = nx.from_scipy_sparse_array(nx.to_scipy_sparse_array(G,weight=None))
print(nx.is_weighted(F)) # True

# Correct solution
drop_weights(F)
print(nx.is_weighted(F)) # False
```

Note that even reconstructing the graph without the weights through `nx.to_scipy_sparse_array` is not enough because the graph is constructed with weights, only these are set to 1.